# Not able to use lazy var in struct in array's firstIndex Method

Tags: ios, swift

I have seen couple of questions but Didn't find solution and a reason

Here is struct

```
struct MovementFormattedData {
   ... Other properties ...
   lazy var timeAsDate:Date?  = {
       return MovementFormattedData.getUTCDate(movementTime: movementTime)
    }()



  static func getUTCDate(movementTime:String?) -> Date? {
        // return date
     }
}
```

Now I have array

```
var movements :[MovementFormattedData] = []
```

When I try

```
  self?.movements.firstIndex(where: {$0.timeAsDate > Date() })
```

I am getting

> Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: '$0' is immutable

I am not modifying $0 anywhere. I am just access the property

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I think initialising `timeAsDate` counts as mutating so a lazy variable might not be what you need.

You could try a computed variable instead so long as you don't need to manually change it.

```swift
var timeAsDate: Date? {
   return MovementFormattedData.getUTCDate(movementTime: movementTime)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use computed properties I want to use lazy property if you can help me with this ?

Comment: If you're not using computed vars you could make it a `class` instead of a `struct`, other than that I'm out of ideas, out of interest can I ask why you are against using computed properties?

Comment: Suppose I have 15k records then it will try to compute every time whenever value required unlike lazy  , I can make it stored property  but I want to know the reason also why it is happening.

Comment: The reason it's not working is because initialising a lazy var is basically mutating it from nil into a value. I don't have a solution though I'm afraid

Comment: I can't accept answer as expected because This is not what I am looking for but you deserves +1

Comment: Thanks, sorry I couldn't be more helpful, also where does the `movementTime` variable come from?

Answer (score 0):

No necessary to use lazy var

```
var timeAsDate: Date? {
    return MovementFormattedData.getUTCDate(movementTime: movementTime)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am aware about computed properties. I don't want to use it if you can help me with this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

lazy property is mutating getter and you cant use it with $0 because $0 is immutable

see following code block

```
struct MovementFormattedData {
   ... Other properties ...
   var timeAsDate: Date? {
       return MovementFormattedData.getUTCDate(movementTime: movementTime)
    }

  static func getUTCDate(movementTime:String?) -> Date? {
        // return date
     }
}

var movements: [MovementFormattedData] = []

self?.movements.firstIndex(where: { $0.timeAsDate ?? Date() > Date() })
```